# How do I parse a string value into a JSON object in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a data source blob that contains JSON data.

One of the entries (nested several objects deep) is a more JSON data that someone upstream of me called a toString() function on in our C# software that is generating the blob.

I need data from the object inside of this string, but unlike with a Kusto Query, where I could just call "parse_json()" I don't know what to do.

Can anyone help me?

An example of what I have follows:

```
{
    "object1": {
        "stringContainingJSON" : "\{\n    \"criticalData1\":\"criticalValue1\",\n    \"criticalData2\":\"criticalValue2\"\n\}"
    }
}
```

To further explain, I need to extract the data in "stringContainingJson" so that I can access it as
`object1.stringContainingJSON.criticalData1`
and
`object1.stringContainingJSON.criticalData2`

Comment: which format you choose,csv or other?Can you show us your screenshot of your pipeline?

Comment: I'm using JSON for my imput source, and I'd like to use JSON for my sink as well.